# Cannot refer to imported jar-library in Android Studio project

Tags: android, import, jar

I have imported an external jar-library `find-local-devices.jar` into Android Studio project. I've put it into `libs` folder, right-clicked and chosen **Add as library**, ensured about dependency in `build.gradle`, cleaned and built again the project - everything as described, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library).
, but I cannot still use the classes from jar:

[image]

Could somebody tell me what I do wrong?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Hong, sorry for delay. No, I didn't. I included code that I need into the project as a source.

Answer (score 3):

Try "Invalidate Caches and restart" on Android Studio.

[image]

EDIT : [image]

Also try deleting you current module and everything referring to it. And add it as the official google documentation is showing you too. The image is from here : https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html

Comment: James Oanta, thanks for quick reply, but it doesn;t help.

Comment: @Spectorsky try the above(edited the answer) exactly as the docs are showing you too do it.

Comment: @JamesOanta Importing a module doesn't mean referring it.

Answer (score 0):

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

try this in gradle file and rebuild

Comment: 정용호, thanks for quick reply. My `build.gradle` already contains `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')` in dependencies, and project was cleaned/rebuilt many times.

Answer (score 0):

Try another way of importing jar/aar packages into Android studio.

> Goto File -> New Module -> import .JAR/.AAR package -> Select file
>   path and say Finish.

Then add this line in Gradle.

```
compile project(':your_imported_file_name')
```

Comment: Shashidhar, thanks for reply. However, it doesn't help.